# Accessing files in Documents folder via jqtouch in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cordova

I was able to save some files in the Documents folder on my app.  How can I access them on the phonegap side of things with jqtouch/javascript/html. I want to do something like:

```
$('#intro').attr('src','../../Documents/logo.png');
```

But, apparently, it's not letting me go up all those directories outside of www.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bundle file reader plugin, but it seems to read the contents, not reference it.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/BundleFileReader

Not sure you can do what you are asking about. Perhaps you could use the PhoneGap File API to save the files somewhere within your www dir instead? Then they would be available via html/js.